# How to run background processes along side discord.py?

Tags: python, multithreading, discord.py

I'm trying to run background worker processes/threads in a Python app I'm working on, but it's somewhat confusing for someone new to Python, the event loops and threads and stuff, plus I'm trying to do this along side or within a Discord bot.

I have it working, but it's gross. The app listens to message queues, has timer-based workers, does some message processing, and potentially creates/deletes/updates message threads in Discord based on the overall state.

The only way I was able to get it to work was to put a `while True` in `on_ready` and listen to the queues in there... I basically only use the bot aspect to update Discord threads. The bot doesn't have to wrap everything else, as far as I'm concerned, but that's the only way I could get it to work.

I would prefer to have the listeners separate and coordinate between those and the bot, running both things concurrently (separate loops/threads) and synchronizing objects or state between them or maybe events. This is how I would do it in C#, but I'm not sure how to do that or what the best way would be in Python.

Comment: you can use `@tasks.loop(seconds=1)` instead of `while True`-loop, and it should run function every 1 second. See doc: [discord.ext.tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html)